# Reading a text file and printing its contents to the screen in C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm writing a function that reads the given file and prints its contents to the screen. At the moment I have the following:

```
int textdump(const char *filename)
{
  int n = 0;
  char ch;
  FILE *fileHandle;
  fileHandle = fopen(filename, "r");
  if ((fileHandle = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
  {
    return -1;
    fclose(fileHandle);
  }
  while ((ch = fgetc(fileHandle) != EOF) )
  {
    printf("%c", ch);
    n++;
  }

  fclose(fileHandle);
  if (fclose(fileHandle) == EOF)
  {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  return n;
}
```

The function reads the text files successfully and returns the number of characters in each file correctly. But then I tried to print the characters and now I even can't run the program - I get "Failed to run - doc cannot be null, can't parse test results".

Comment: You open the file twice!

Comment: `return -1; fclose(fileHandle);` <-- this does not make sense. `fclose` after `return` means `fclose` is never called, which is not a bad thing, seeing as `fileHandle` will be `NULL` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while ( (ch = fgetc(fileHandle) != EOF) )
```

should be

```
while ( (ch = fgetc(fileHandle)) != EOF)
```

You need to take care of operator precedence. With the posted code `ch = fgetc()` will not be evaluated first as you think so add parenthesis to make sure that you bind them together as shown above.

Comment: In other words: in the first version, the value of the expression `fgetc(fileHandle) != EOF` is assigned to `ch`, which is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @DarkDust true that!!

Answer (score 6):

To summarize the issues with above code,

- In your code, why you're `fopen()`/ `fclose()`-ing twice? Get rid of that part. ---------------(1)
- You need not `fclose()` what is not already opened. ----------------------------------------------(2)
- All the statements after `return` is of no effect. ------------------------------------------------------(3)
- Take care of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) while using `fgetc()`. -----------------------------------------(4)
- [`fgetc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) returns `int` value. Change acccordingly. -----------------------------------------------(5)

So, your code will look like

```
int textdump(const char *filename)
{
int n = 0;
int ch = 0;
FILE *fileHandle = NULL;
//fileHandle = fopen(filename, "r");  //not reqd  --- (1)
    if ((fileHandle = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
    return -1;
    //fclose(fileHandle); // not reqd  --- (2), (3)
}
while ( (ch = fgetc(fileHandle)) != EOF ){   //notice here   -- (4), (5)
  printf("%c", ch);
  n++;
}

fclose(fileHandle);
/*
if(fclose(fileHandle) == EOF){ -- (1)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }*/
 return n;
 }
```

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: No, he isn't. The first call is commented out.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Didn't pay attention to the syntax highlighting and mistook the commented `fopen` call for an actual call. My appologies

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem No issues at all Sir. Rather, thanks for reviewing my post. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
int textdump(const char *filename)
{
    int n = 0;
    FILE *fileHandle;
    /* char ch; fgetc wants an int (able to store EOF) not a char */
    int ch;
    fileHandle = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fileHandle == NULL){
        /* return -1; */ 
        /* fclose(fileHandle); */
        /* you can not close what is not oppened */
        perror("fopen");
        return -1;
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fileHandle)) != EOF) /* Beware of the precedence */
        printf("%c", ch);
        n++;
    }
    /* You don't need to check the result of fclose
    if(fclose(fileHandle) == EOF){ 
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    */
    fclose(fileHandle);
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough

```
int textdump(const char * filename) {
    int n = 0, c;
    FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return -1;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) putchar(c), n++;
    fclose(fp);
    return n;
}
```